# Include child elements in ng-include directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am including a template from script tag to HTML DOM.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
  <p>Content of the template.</p>
</script>


<div ng-include src="'/tpl.html'"><p>This should also be included</p></div>
```

Now when the template is included the `<p>` element is removed. I want that

content together with the HTML of `/tpl.html`

Comment: You are using `ng-include` wrong, no need of `src` attribute use `ng-include="'/tpl.html'"`

Comment: We can use src. But stil after i removed src i don't get the <p> element inside that div

Answer (score 0):

What are trying to include ? p tag is inside script element???

Create a new template `tpl.html`

```
<div>
 <p>Content of the template.</p>
</div>

<div ng-include ="'/tpl.html'"><p>This should also be included</p></div>
```

This is how it works in angular...